# Controlling many stepper motors (not necessarily simulataneously)?

Tags: gpio, spi

I would like to have an array of N stepper motors, and "step" a subset of this array once per second.

Being completely simultaneous is not a requirement as long as any subset (from 1 to N, averaging N/3 say) can be stepped in the span of 1 second.

It looks like with GPIO and various expansions I can do this simultaneously for relatively small values of N (ie < 100), but I think to really scale this (N > 100) I need to make this more asynchronous.

The end goal is a line of N stepper motors that can each toggle a display of M different things-- for example a continuously updating display of stock prices.

What kind of solution am I looking for here? I am new to this..

Comment: describing what you are trying to accomplish may help us answer your question.

Comment: Good idea, updated the description, I hope my goal is more clear.